# Table and cell creation

Tags: c#, html-table, cells

I'm creating a HtmlTable with a for loop and I want to know why I can't modify the cells for each row.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   row = new HtmlTableRow();
   mainTbl.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Whenever I try the code below I receive an out of index range error. Why?

```
mainTbl.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text = "A"
mainTbl.Rows[1].Cells[2].Text = "B"
mainTbl.Rows[2].Cells[3].Text = "B"
```

Comment: I think,you must add cells to rows before adding them to collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think,you must add cells to rows before adding them to collection. Something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   row = new HtmlTableRow();
   for(int j=0;j<3;++j)
   {
      row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell());
   }
   mainTbl.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that, but that resolved my problem. Thanks Hamlet!